# How to find the first x occurrences of a Char in a String using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

i'm trying to find out how i can get the first x Matches of a Char in a String. I tried using a Matchcollection but i cant find any escapesequence to stop after the x'd-match.

FYI:
I need this for a string with a variable length and a different number of occurences of the searched Char, so just getting all and using only the first x isnt a solution.

Thanks in advance

Edit:
I am using steam reader to get information out of a .txt files and write it to a atring, for each file one string. These atrings have very different lengths. In every string are lets say 3 keywords. But sometimes something went wrong and i have only one or two of the keywords. Between the keywords are other fields separated with a ;. So if i use a Matchcollection to get the indexes of the ;'s and one Keyword is missing the Information in the File is shifted. Because of that i need to find the first x occourencces before/after a (existing)keyword.

Comment: any reason why you are using regex?

Comment: could you add a sample of what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Does the solution have to be a regex? what if there's another solution that can find the first x occurrences of c? Why is finding all and only using x not a solution?

Comment: @pabuc: my boss loves regex and i'm trying to learn it. what would you use??

Comment: Can you clarify if you're looking for a single char in a string, or a substring ? Also, what determines the value of X ?

Comment: When all you have is a hammer...

Comment: @RuneFS2: the string has a different lenght and i need  the Index i get from the match to start reading out information from the Data so i need to look ifpoint a(a different string) exists and then look for the next 3; for example, but if it dosnt exists everything else gets shifted so hat wont work(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: ...trimming your nasal hair is difficult ?

Comment: @mono: so, based on your comment to V4Vendettas answer you have a string of variable length and want to search for a specific character for X times and as a result have the index positions of all x occurances of specified character? I'm not sure RegEx can do that without any looping code around it

Comment: @mono I would use string.IndexOf..

Comment: @Andreas: LOL exactly! Everything looks like a nail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want to use Regex, something like this won't do ?

```
string simpletext = "Hello World";
int firstoccur = simpletext.IndexOfAny(new char[]{'o'});
```

---

Since you want all the indexes for that character you can try in this fashion

```
string simpletext = "Hello World";
int[] occurences = Enumerable.Range(0, simpletext.Length).Where(x => simpletext[x] == 'o').ToArray();
```

Comment: No i dont think this will work, because i need a int[] with every index of 'o'. But maybe your right that regex is not the right way to do this. Thanks

Comment: a int[] with every index of 'o' is exactly what the second code snippet will get you

Comment: @Serge: your right but he wrote that later, look at the Times. No offense

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Thank you very mutch, i think i can edit this so that it fits exactly to my problem, if not I'll be back :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class `Match`. this class returns only one result, but you can iterate over the string till it found the last one.

Something like this:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
int count = 0;

while (match.Success)
{
    count++;

    // do something with match

    match = match.NextMatch();

    // Exit the loop when your match number is reached
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're determined to use Regex then I'd do this with Matches as opposed to Match actually; largely because you get the count up front.

```
string pattern = "a";
string source = "this is a test of a regex match";
int maxMatches = 2;

MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(source, pattern);

if (mc.Count() > 0)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < maxMatches; i++) 
  {
    //do something with mc[i].Index, mc[i].Length
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is very close but does not excatly get the Job done. I think i need to clearify my Question. So i will edit. Thany you very mutch.

Answer (score 0):

The split operation is pretty fast so if the regex is not a requirement this could be used:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> IndicesOf(this string text, char value, int count)
        {
            var tokens = text.Split(value);
            var sum = tokens[0].Length;
            var currentCount = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < tokens.Length && 
                            sum < text.Length && 
                            currentCount < count; i++)
            {
                yield return sum;
                sum += 1 + tokens[i].Length;
                currentCount++;
            }
        }
```

executes in roughly 60% of the time of the regex